# Namespace specification

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to use the simpliest  message box in my console program( empty C# project type selected).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace roughDraft
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello :)");

            Console.ReadKey();           
        }
    }
}
```

> The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

As you can see in this case program doesn't work, athough I used exactly the same namespace as specified in [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3.aspx).

Why it's no problem when using less specified namespace, i.e. System.Windows? How to decide whether to "cut" or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll`  to use that.To add the reference,follow the following step:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click on the project node and click Add Reference.
2. In the Add Reference dialog box, select the `.NET` tab and choose `System.Windows.Forms` and click OK.

Answer (score 4):

Namespaces are not "just there". You need to include references to .NET DLLs to get access to namespaces. For example, the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace is defined in the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` dll. Creating a console application, this DLL is not referenced. So to use it, you need to reference it.

If you have created a WPF application, you can not by default use the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. Either you need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing`, or you use `System.Windows.MessageBox`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you what the problem is: you are missing a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll`. Once you [add the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) there will be no issue.